# Handling photo resizing PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I have an application with an upload form that allows users to upload a photo. There may be 1000 people online and each once could be uploading their own photo.

My question is: Should I resize uploaded photo immediately after upload, or create cron, which will resize all uploaded photos at night?

Comment: The internet never sleeps. ;)

Comment: Could you just have a default avatar that everyone uses until their photo is processed?

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, photo resizing isn't an extremely slow process, pending the server's resources of course (and I guess the size of the image might be a factor - given a 10MB+ image).

I would fully recommend doing the resize immediately after upload. Doing this won't build a queue at 3am or whenever your cron runs, and you'll also have the benefit of displaying the resized image (thumbnail maybe, half-page size, etc.) to the user that just uploaded it - pretty much a "must" in user experience.

Comment: Size of picture is limited to 5 MB and Imagick is not an option, all images will be processed via GD.

Comment: @Frees That's fine - I normally use the `imagecreatefrom*` methods - and they all use GD; never had any issues doing immediate resizing.

Answer (score 0):

A cron job is an excellent asset because you wouldn't tax your server as much because you could run it at 4am.

However, what about your user's browsers that with be downloading that image before the cron job ever completes? :( Think about your users and make the server fast enough to resize the pictures immediately. Also, you might want to look into optimizing the photos too!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cron for that, but your users have to wait a long time before there picture is taken care of.
I would suggest using a second server, and a waiting list where you put all the pictures in that need to be re-sized. The second server handles the pictures one by one (1 minutes crontab) and puts them back at the first server. This way your users wont have to wait so long, and your fist server won't be overloaded with image that needs to be resized.

If you want to use just one server, you can just add a cron and resize your pictures with nice, ionice and imagemagick.

While the image is being processed you can place a placeholder for the images, letting your visitors know their image is being processed.